# How to set up the property inside container to get the below shape?

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, shapes

This is the ui layout I want to create but finally which I got was the second one.

The code for the bottom widget of second image is here

```
              Container(
                        height: 150,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "A Project of Pera E16’ME",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "NovaMono",
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(1000),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(1000)),
                          color: Color(0xff08367A),
                        ),
                      )
```

How can I change the code above to get a shape like which is in one

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should either use a [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) or a [CustomClipper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomClipper-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use dependency **flutter_custom_clippers: ^2.0.0** [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) hope its help to you and you also try another shapes also in this plugin